# Google Picker API with already saved username and password

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-api, google-picker

I've implemented `Google Picker API` which pops up a window asking for `Google authentication` and then shows us all the files available in the Google Drive.
everything works fine.

But now my requirement is, I need to access the files in the drive with out that authentication popup. I'll have the username and password saved in my Database.

Is there any way to pass the user credentials and get authorized and access the files?

My code :

```
<script>
  function onApiLoad() {
    gapi.load('auth', { 'callback': onAuthApiLoad });
    gapi.load('picker');
  }

function onAuthApiLoad() {
   window.gapi.auth.authorize({                         
   'client_id': 'xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
   'scope': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    }, handleAuthResult);
}

var oauthToken;
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
   if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
      createPicker();
   }
}


function createPicker() {                    
   var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
                .addView(new google.picker.DocsView())                        
                .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                .setDeveloperKey('xxxx')                           
                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
                .addView(new google.picker.VideoSearchView().setSite(google.picker.VideoSearchView.YOUTUBE))
                .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                .build();
                 picker.setVisible(true);
      }
</script>
```

Comment: A word of caution that you should not be storing Google passwords without a very very good and specific reason. If this is just a project for yourself it's not so bad but you really shouldn't do it for other users.

Comment: you should be storing refresh token not user name and password.  Its the point of Open Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

While creating picker i.e createpicker() send the access token so that It wont prompt for the consent screen. IN your code change createpicker() to createPicker(oauthToken). Please find the example code snippet:

```
function createPicker(token) {
 if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {


 var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
       .addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true)) //All files and Folders            

     .setOAuthToken(token)//Access Token

     .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
     .setCallback(pickerCallback)
     // Instruct Picker to fill the dialog, minus 2 pixels for the border.
     .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width ,
         DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height )
     .build();
 picker.setVisible(true);
} else {
 showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
}
}
```

Comment: how can we get that pickerApiLoaded= true ?

Comment: @SGC This does not solve the problem. I am facing similar issue. Even after sending access token, an authentication screen appears where you have to give username and pw

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code by passing your access_token..

```
    function createPicker(access_token) {
 if (access_token) {
  var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsView())                        
            .setOAuthToken(access_token)
            .setDeveloperKey('xxxx')                           
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
            .addView(new google.picker.VideoSearchView().setSite(google.picker.VideoSearchView.YOUTUBE))
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .build();
             picker.setVisible(true);
} else {
 showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
}
}
```